# How do I easily view the values of Output-only Patches?

Tags: quartz-composer

I'm losing my sanity with so much Quartz Composer Input/Output data flowing around on my screen and in my head.

Am I missing what appears to be a much needed function of Quartz Composer? I'm attempting to do some work with receiving MIDI signals, and as of yet I haven't been able to prove that the messages are actually making it to QC.

Is there a way, shy of hoving over the output/input and hoping the tooltip updates on change, to show an overall current status of changing values on a selected, or group of patches and all of their values?

I'll remind you that 3 of the 4 MIDI patches are output-only, so the inspector does not have any location to show their output values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  This is an inherent problem of the way QC is designed.

My advice:  **simplify**.  Save a backup copy of the composition, then delete everything except the (hopefully small) part you want to test.  Once you've verified that's working (or fixed it), repeat, but with a larger chunk of the composition.

Also, for specifically viewing MIDI output, http://www.snoize.com/MIDIMonitor/ has been really helpful for me.